# $scope variable 'undefined' using array.prototype.foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this following directive

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('rcLevel', ['spreadsheet', rcLevel]);

  function rcLevel(spreadsheet) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        record: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'js/directives/rcLevel.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.spreadsheet = spreadsheet.data;
        $scope.propsOpen = false;
        $scope.props = Object.keys($scope.record.properties).length > 0;
        $scope.level = level($scope.record);
        console.log($scope.level);

        // Logic

        function level(record) {

          $scope.spreadsheet.forEach(function(row) {
            if (row.Name.indexOf(record.event) > -1) {
              console.log('Highlighting: level' + row.Level);
              return 'level' + row.Level;
            }
          });
        }

      }

    };
  }
})();
```

I use it with `ng-repeat`. Everything works fine, however, `$scope.level` is said to be undefined.

Console logging inside `level` function works fine, but console logging `$scope.level` says 'undefined'.

I am trying to accomplish highlighting certain rows in `ng-repeat` based on the data from `spreadsheet`, so I am attaching the required class to `$scope.level` and then in the code using it as `ng-class="level"`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should correct it :

```
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.spreadSheets.length; ++i) {
        if ($scope.spreadSheets[i].Name.indexOf(record.event) > -1) {
          console.log('Highlighting: level' + row.Level);
          return 'level' + $scope.spreadSheets[i].Level;
        }
      });
```

Explanation :
The function inside foreach returns something that is not propagated anywhere. What you did is kind of following :

```
function a(){
   b();
}

function b(){
   return true;
}

if (a()) => always falsy
```

**Edit**

I changed the foreach into a for loop which looks more suitable in your case

Comment: @Idefixx I'm not sure what I did is enough. I'll make some checks and come back

Comment: you did think correctly, but your solution doesn't work. what i did was add a `var result` then attach the `'level' + row.Level` to it, then return `result`. works now

Comment: @Idefixx I did not see your last comment before editing my answer. Your solution was my first idea but I think a for is better is this case (it won't iterate through the whole array when one of the conditions matches)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `level` may be not returning the value, modify the function like this

```
if (row.Name.indexOf(record.event) > -1) {
              console.log('Highlighting: level' + row.Level);
              return 'level' + row.Level;
}else{
             return 'hello world';
}
```

Then if the line `console.log($scope.level);` shows `hello world`, alter the logic of the function `level()`